# Compare two identical table structure on different database for different data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdo, date-comparison

I know this question is similar to a previously answered question such as

[How to compare data between two table in different databases using Sql Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606175/how-to-compare-data-between-two-table-in-different-databases-using-sql-server-20)

[Compare two identical tables MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171288/compare-two-identical-tables-mysql)

But my concern here is, what if the two databases are in DIFFERENT locations? How would the SQL query look like?

To clarify, I have two MySQL servers, let's name the first server *MONITOR*, and the second server *SNAPSHOT*. Server *MONITOR* is used and maintained by a third party inventory management software. Server *SNAPSHOT* is my custom MySQL server that stores *MONITOR*'s key tables and makes comparisons. Both of the servers have the same database named INVENTORY and a table named HARDWARE.

The SQL command in the above two links is exactly what I am striving for, however, since the databases are on two different servers, both requires different username/logins, which makes the SQL command fails to execute, and I'm seeking if there's a solution to this.

Also, another question being, in the case of both tables having large amounts of data (say over a million entries), would it be recommended for me to dump the *MONITOR*'s table into *SNAPSHOT*'s database first, and run the comparison query on the *SNAPSHOT* server?

PS: I would like both a PHP/PDO and a SQL solution, just to compare which method is much suited for a large scale process, if possible.

**Questions that people might ask:**

**Q:** Why don't you make both databases on *MONITOR*?

**A:** Because we wouldn't want if *MONITOR* goes down, the platform which uses *SNAPSHOT*'s comparison goes down with it. Also, since *MONITOR* is generated and maintained by a third party software, we would like to interact as little as possible with it.

**Q:** Can't you write a trigger when *MONITOR*'s data got updated and forward that to *SNAPSHOT*?

**A:** As mentioned above, we prefer not to touch the database generated by the third party to prevent possible errors/corruptions.

Comment: You could create linked servers and do the monitoring as a separate third party service.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne How would I do that?

Comment: On Something like MS SQL, create a linked server to each MySQL (I do that with redmine - for SSRS reporting).   See answer below for linked server creation.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the "MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver".

Add the below procedure (making it easier to add additional servers)

```
    --http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx
    ALTER PROC uspCreateLinkToMySQLDB @linkedservername varchar(50), @mysqlip varchar(50), @dbname varchar(100), @username varchar(50), @password varchar(50) AS
    --@linkedservername = the name you want your linked server to have
    --@mysqlip = the ip address of your mysql database
    --@dbname = the name of the mysql database you want to operate against. Without this, some of the features of openquery fail
    --@username = the username you will use to connect to the mysql database
    --@password = the password used by your username to connect to the mysql database

    BEGIN
    --DROP THE LINKED SERVER IF IT EXISTS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT srv.name FROM sys.servers srv WHERE srv.server_id != 0 AND srv.name = @linkedservername)
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=@linkedservername, @droplogins='droplogins'

    --ADD THE LINKED SERVER
    DECLARE @ProviderString varchar(1000)

    Select @ProviderString = 'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};SERVER=' + @mysqlip + ';Port=3306;OPTION=3;DATABASE=' + @dbname + ';'

    EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server=@linkedservername, 
    @srvproduct='MySQL',
    @provider='MSDASQL', 
    @provstr=@ProviderString

    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@linkedservername, @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
    EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @linkedservername, 'false', NULL, @username, @password
    END
```

Now run "uspCreateLinkToMySQLDB 'HLP_BB', '172.19.49.181', 'bitnami_redmine', '{Your Mysql User}', '{Password of Admin}'"

Success!

Query from MySQL:

select * from HLP_BB...{Whatever table}

NOTE:  Remember that mysql user permissions is often linked to the IP address, so be sure to change / check that based on where you are accessing it from.

Then you can link and test.  Using some temp table or in-memory tables may help to mitigate the delays or limit the data coming from the other servers / databases.